# LinQ Grouping records with null values

Tags: linq, code-first

I have a table and need to get list by grouping Field1 and Field2

```
public class Journal
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string DateField { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public int Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

First of all I filter data by Field2 (string) and when grouping by two fields (Field1 and Field2)

```
MyList = DBContext.Journals.Where(f=>f.Field2.StartsWith(someParam))
                           .GroupBy(g => new { g.Field1, g.Field2 })
                           .Select(n=> n.Key.Field1).ToList();
```

If Field1 and Field2 is not null, everything is ok, but how to solve a problem if they are null, could You help?

If there are nulls, I got an exception:

> "The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."

Comment: Field1 can't ever be null -- it's a value type.

Comment: Use `public int? Field1 { get; set; }` in `Journal` ;).

Comment: And what about MyList?   List<int> MyList = new List<int>(); ?

Comment: @Songaila Did you try doing a null check ? Something like: `DBContext.Journals.Where(f => ! (f.Field2 == null || f.Field2.Equals(string.Empty)
) && f.Field2.StartsWith(someParam))`

Comment: A bigest problem for me is about that int type field... with string is ok

Answer (score 1):

have you tried maybe with something like:

```
MyList = DBContext.Journals.Where(f=> !String.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Field1) && f.Field2 != null && (f.Field2.StartsWith(someParam)))
                           .GroupBy(g => new { g.Field1, g.Field2 })
                           .Select(n=> n.Key.Field1).ToList();
```

Comment: int Field2.      The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?' But it is always true, why I get an exception about null... how to solve this problem in entity framework, not in server by filtering nullable records (I need them too, even if they are null)